# Inno Setup... app crashes silently if not run as Admin

Tags: windows-vista, inno-setup

I built a little installer, which installs to program files. I run the installer and all is good, run the installed .exe and it just disappears. I guess at giving the EXE admin launch rights in Vista and it runs. But why is this needed? This can't be normal can it?

Comment: What happens if you install your application into Program Files with administrative privileges and execute it normally, via the explorer? Does the application still silently die?

Comment: Yes it does. I think it's a file write problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may be your application that is crashing, and completely unrelated to Inno Setup. Bear in mind that if your application is installed to `Program Files`, it can *read* but cannot *modify* files inside the installation directory without administrator privileges.

You should instead use the `AppData\Roaming` folder. Perhaps your application is falling over an unhandled exception while writing to a file while access to it is denied?

**Edit:**

To have Inno remove the restrictive permissions on your installation directory, add the following to your Inno Setup script:

```
[Dirs]
Name: "{app}\"; Permissions: everyone-modify
```

Comment: It's not an Inno problem, but I expected the installer to sort this out. Joe's link may have helped. The issue is almost certainly that the app tries to modify a file in its own dir, which requires admin access.

Comment: You can have Inno change the permissions on the installation directory so that administrative privileges are not required. I'll update my answer in a moment with the setup script.

Comment: Is Inno able to do this even on Windwos folders like Program Files\MyApp?

Comment: Yes, it is! The permissions on the Program Files folder can be modified with administrator privileges, so if you grant the setup application permission via a UAC dialog, it can modify them.

Answer (score 1):

What version of Inno Setup are you using?

http://www.vincenzo.net/isxkb/index.php?title=Vista_considerations

This states you need 5.3.7 for standard-user-only installs as a minimum.  It also defines which things you can and can't do for a standard user installer.

Comment: 5.3.8... but it turns out I need admin-level install. The issue was without that, I simply didn't know the .exe needed it... rather than complain it just quit.

Answer (score 1):

If your application requires full administrator privileges in order to run correctly, you might consider bundling a manifest file with your executable, containing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <v3:trustInfo xmlns:v3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <v3:security>
      <v3:requestedPrivileges>
        <v3:requestedExecutionLevel level="highestAvailable"/>
      </v3:requestedPrivileges>
    </v3:security>
  </v3:trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

This can be done fairly easily from many IDEs, but if you already have an executable and only want to associate a manifest file with it, [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista-security/MakingAppsUACAware.aspx) describes the best practices in doing so.